# SQL Server: Return results when not duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

I just can't seem to get my mind wrapped around this.  To simplify as much as possible, let's say I have a table:

```
Id      cid         Account
1       4010        Bank Co
2       5323        Webazon
3       3513        Internal
4       3513        PhoneCo
5       5597        Internal
```

I'm wanting to return all results except for the lines that are Account = 'Internal' where there's also a customer with the same cid.  So, in this case, we would return lines 1,2,4, and 5.  Line 3 would not be returned, because 'PhoneCo' and 'Internal' share cid 3513.  However, line 5 would be returned because there's not another record that shares cid 5597.

I'm going down the road of doing it with a UNION, where the first part is eliminating all 'Internal' records, and the second part is just those I'm interested in, but I may be going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.account <> 'Internal' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.cid = t.cid and t2.account <> 'Internal'
                 );
```

That is, select everything all non-internal records.  And, select records for internal accounts where there is not a corresponding non-internal account.

Comment: That looks like it works.  I just sometimes have trouble getting my head wrapped around SQL world.  Thanks!